# Calling remote API with "async" in ASMX webservice not working

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, openai-api

I am trying to call a remote API from OpenAI. However, I want to call the remote API via my C# ASMX web service. (ASP.NET webforms project .NET 4.7)

The problem I am facing is the the remote call does not completed, i.e. the execution does not go beyond "Result", and there is no error or anything else. It just hangs.

Any ideas?

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public async Task<string> InitializeAI(string question) {
 
string OpenAIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OpenAI-APIKey"].ToString();
OpenAIAPI api = new OpenAIAPI(OpenAIKey);

var t = "AI:Hi, how are you.\nHuman:I am well.";

            try
            {
                CompletionResult Result = await api.Completions.CreateCompletionAsync(new CompletionRequest(t, temperature: 0.1, stopSequences: " Human:, AI:")).Wait();             
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            return await Task.FromResult("ascb");          
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you call this API directly using a testing tool like Postman. Also be aware that asmx is ancient technology.

Comment: ASMX is ancient. Agree. The remote API works fine when called directly from Postman. Works fine from C# console app also and also from Azure functions app too. Just not ASMX.